# Escribir snap de evento de tabla realtime con FuntionsCloud en Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

Tengo una instancia llamada `AP` la cual deseo crear una function que cuando se agrege un nuevo dato se agrege ese dato otra instancia en la misma base de datos llamada `SA` he intentado sin exito de la siguiente manera con el evento `onCreate`;

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.addSa = functions.database
.ref('AP')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const datos = snapshot.val();

    return snapshot.ref.parent.child('SA').set(datos);
});
```

fui a la herramienta de test function de google y al ejecutarla lo que hace es que elimina completamente la instancia `SA`. Otra cosa que me llamo la atención fue el registro de la function es el siguiente:

```
11:31:54.521 a.m.
addSa
Function execution took 1658 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

====
11:31:52.916 a.m.
addSa
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions

====


11:31:52.916 a.m.
addSa
Function execution started
```

No se por que debo agregar datos de facturación, la verdad estoy bastante confundido. agradezco la ayuda que puedan prestarme.

Comment: Solo es un warning, ya que si estas usando el plan Spark solo puedes usar 125,000 invocaciones al mes, por lo que si te pasas de ese monto, dejara de funcionar tu aplicativo. Por lo que te recomienda poner tu tarjeta para que no suceda eso, pero si solo es para hacer pruebas y crees que no te pasaras de ese numero no pasa nada :D. Saludos. Fuente: https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Comment: gracias por aclarar la duda de la advertencia, ya me quedo claro, ahora falta solucionar el por que la funcion no me realizar la tarea :(

Comment: En tu otra pregunta usando javascript, ya actualize mi respuesta

Comment: En vez de usar `snapshot.val()` intenta con `snapshot.after.data()` Saludos.